# Python string search: how to find exact matches, and not match with strings that contain searched string in them

Tags: python, loops, search, match

I need my script to bring up definitions for different words.

I'm using a loop to look for matches between between an item in a string (X) and and array.

```
if any(i in X for i in ('coconut, Coconut')):
    print("found coconut")

if any(i in X for i in ('nut', 'Nut')):
    print("found nut")
```

The problem is, when the item in array X is a word containing another word (e.g. coconut & nut), both prints are executed.

How do I make sure that when there's an item called coconut in array X, I only get a print for coconut, and not for nut?

I'll be eternally grateful for any help.

Comment: Test for equality, `i == X`?

Comment: show an example of `X`.

Comment: Please be clear about what `X` is - you refer to a string and an array. From the execution of your code, it must be a string, but your question is ambiguously phrased.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for equality of the individual strings, rather than the presence of a word in the `X` array (normally called a `list` in python, unless you are using `numpy`):

```
if any(i == x for i in ('coconut', 'Coconut') for x in X):
    print("found coconut")

if any(i == x for i in ('nut', 'Nut') for x in X):
    print("found nut")
```

or better yet, you can convert the test string to lowercase first so that only a single for loop is necessary for each word:

```
if any(x.lower() == "coconut" for x in X):
    print("Found coconut")
```

This works unless you want to differentiate proper nouns, such as to propose a different definition for Jersey and jersey.

If `X` is a string, a simple equality check will work for this:

```
if X.lower() == "coconut":
    print("Found coconut")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work - i in X tests whether the substring i is found in the string X, while this tests whether they're equivalent.

```
if any(i == X for i in ('nut', 'Nut'):
    print('found nut')
```

Comment: X is a list, rather than a string.

Comment: @dspencer `X` is a string as the OP says `a string (X) `

Comment: "How do I make sure that when there's an item called coconut in array X" from the question, which is very ambiguous, as they do also refer to it as a string, yes.

Comment: well, what about the first part of his question?

Comment: @dspencer his issue it makes sense only in a string not in a list, you can check

Answer (score 0):

you could trasnsform your string `X` into a set:

```
sx = set(X.split()) # to get the words you may use a regex, depending of how X looks
if sx & {'coconut, Coconut'}:
    print("found coconut")
```

Comment: According to the question, `X` is an "array", which I presume to be a list, rather than a string.

Comment: It seems the question is ambiguous in what X is: "How do I make sure that when there's an item called coconut in array X". From the behaviour of their code, it must be a string, but the ambiguity is a sign of a poorly phrase question.

Comment: @dspencer yes  you are right the question is ambiguous, but the OP issue doesn't make sense if X is a list

Comment: Agreed. Although, based on the `in` test, I wonder if the OP is treating/expecting `X` to be a list - such a test would be an illogical dictionary lookup if `X` were a string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I've figured it out.

In this case, it was enough simply to add a space before the shorter keyword.